# Declaring CSS in HTML doc, Append or overwrite?

Tags: html, css

So I have a pretty newbie question regarding HTML and CSS. I just started utilizing Twitter's Bootstrap framework, and have this bit of code in the head of my index.html file:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Custom CSS Overwrite-->
<style type="text/css">
    html{overflow-y:scroll;} <!-- Fixes "page shift" issue -->
</style>
```

The bootstrap.css file defines this, like so:

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Does my declared CSS in the html file overwrite or append the `html{}` for the CSS? I'm hoping it's append, because overwrite might screw things up down the road.

The reason I don't just edit the bootstrap.css file is because I read it's good practice to not edit the bootstrap.css file so that future upgrades go as smoothly as possible.

BTW if anyone is wondering what the `overflow-y:scroll` is for it's to include a vertical scroll bar in your browser at all times, whether there's scrollable material or not. Fixes the dreaded "page shift" issue, it's the simplest solution I could find so far.

Comment: Due to the cascading nature of CSS, this will overwrite the rule (if stated) in the bootstrap CSS. But only the overflow rule, nothing else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will append it on. (Unless Bootstrap has changed the `overflow-y` property of the html element.)

This almost always happens in CSS.

So this:

```
.foo {
    background-color: red;
}
.foo {
    color: green;
}
```

Is the same as:

```
.foo {
    background-color: red;
    color: green;
}
```

The only time it doesn't apply is when you change the same value, because in CSS, you can't have multiple values on properties.

---

I don't know if Bootstrap has an `overflow-y` property added on to the `<html>` element. If it does your page shift issue css will overwrite that. If it doesn't then it will be "appended" on.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Bootstrap does not have an overflow-y property in it's <html> element :)